# Set default account in Empathy metacontact

Tags: empathy, contacts, messaging-menu

When I link contacts in empathy, facebook becomes the default account used in a new chat.

Is there a way to change the default account? I'd like to avoid using facebook whenever possible, and instead have different preferred accounts to use for different people.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _new chat_?

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/empathy/+bug/779071) and as such is now closed. Please track progress on that bug tracker site.

Answer (score 0):

I gave this a try and I see what you mean. When you link contacts together, the accounts have some kind of sorting applied.

For me: MSN accounts always come before GTalk accounts and accounts for the same protocol are sorted alphabetically. I'm guessing this is because my MSN name comes before my gtalk name in the alphabet.

Double clicking on your meta contact to start a chat uses the first account in the sorted list. (Fortunately, the sorting also takes into account the user's status.)

I think the inability to set a default account is a bug. Please report it with `ubuntu-bug empathy`.

Comment: Ok I reported it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/empathy/+bug/779071 thanks